# PHP Connecting to Twitter API and storing to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, twitter

I'm brand new to the world of databases...  I'm trying to connect to the twitter API from a search query and than post the results to a database in mysql (creating the database in the process if no database exists)...  I apologize if my code is kind of scattered and fragmented, this is a group project for a class and my group isn't exactly the cleanest of coders...   Any ideas/thoughts or pointing out anything that seems to be done incorrectly would be a huge help.  Thanks...

After typing in a query, this is the error received:

```
The twitter
Database does not exist. Creating it now .... 
Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterDB\database\database.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterDB\database\database.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'sesame') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterDB\searchDB.php(8): Database->__construct('twitter') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterDB\database\database.php on line 17

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\TwitterDB\database\database.php on line 17
```

This is my database.php

```
class Database {
    var $db;

    public function __construct($dbname) {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' .$dbname;
        $username = 'root';
        $password = 'sesame';

        try {
            $this ->db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo '<br> The <b>' .$dbname . '<br> Database does not exist. Creating it now ....  <b>';
            try {
                $this ->db = new PDO('localhost', $username, $password);
                $sql = "create database twitter;
                        use twitter;
                        create table tweets(
                        id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                        date dateTime,
                        from_user_id INT,
                        from_user_name VARCHAR(30),
                        to_user_id INT,
                        to_user_name VARCHAR(30),
                        geo VARCHAR(30),
                        profile_image_url VARCHAR(200),
                        text VARCHAR(150),
                        PRIMARY KEY (id, date, from_user_id)
                        )";

                $this ->db ->exec($sql);
                echo 'Done!<br>';

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e ->getMessage();
                exit();

            }

        }
    }


public function close() {
    try {
        $this ->db - null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e ->getMessage() . "Exit!";
        exit();

    }
}

   public function insertTweets($tweets) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO TWEETS
        (id, date, from_user_id, from_user_name, profile_image_url, text)
        VALUES (:id, :date, :from_user_id, :from_user_name, :profile_image_url, :text)";
    try {
        $x = $this ->db ->prepare($sql);
        foreach($tweets as $t) {
            $parameters = array(
                ':id'=> $t ->id,
                ':date'=> date('Y-m-d- H:i:s', strtotime($t ->date)),
                ':from_user_id'=> $t ->from_user_id,
                ':from_user_name'=> $t ->from_user_name,
                ':profile_image_url'=> $t ->profile_image_url,
                ':text'=> $t ->text
                );

            $x ->execute($parameters);

        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die ('Insert attempt failed:' . $e -> getMessage());

    }
}


public function clearTable() {
    try {
        $x = $this ->db ->prepare('TRUNCATE TABLE tweets');
        $x = execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Attempt failed:' . $e ->getMessage());

    }
  }



public function search($query) {
    try {
        $x = $this ->db ->prepare($query);
        $x -> execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die ('Query failed:' . $e -> getMessage());

    }

    echo '<table border = 1>';

    $heading = true;
    while ( ($row = $x -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
        echo '<tr>';

        if ($heading) {
            $keys = array_keys($row);
            foreach ($keys as $k) {
                echo '<th>' .$k . '<th>';

            }
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $heading = false;

        } 
        foreach($row as $r => $v) {
            echo '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
  }    
}
```

This is my insertDB.php

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "3219120843-cvff5Rj8LeFnmm6aM2eSdWN7bEKRwmjnJW64Wms",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "MZS2Om2TRr9e56fgLAjWx7iwX3n7Svz18ya5iAXyWeMQS",
    'consumer_key' => "y4sArn9Zl4DaA8KTPLIxFXVh8",
    'consumer_secret' => "5Yj9soIQtLoQqbiXIgo1PhMSvI5sExsg13REHWGa1pPTzhTr2p"
);


$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';



$getfield = '?q='.$_POST['keyword'];
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$result = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)

                        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)

                        ->performRequest();

$tweets = json_decode($result);

$tweet = $tweets->statuses;

echo $result;


require 'data_model.php';
$records = tweets2array($tweet);

require 'view.php';
echo tweet_obj_array2table($records);

$tweets = json_decode($result)->results;

$objects = tweets2array($tweets);

echo 'Total tweets:' . count($objects);

$database = new Database('twitter');

$table = 'tweets';

$database -> insertTweets($objects);

$database -> close();

?>
```

And this is my datamodel.php

```
<?php

function tweets2array($tweets) {
    $records = array();
    foreach($tweets as $tweet) {
        $t = new stdClass();
        $t->sender = $tweet->user->name;
        $t->text = $tweet->text;
        $t->time = $tweet->created_at;
        $t->image = $tweet->user->profile_image_url;
        $records[] = $t;
    }
    return $records;
}

 ?>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for an 'Access denied' message. What do you think that might mean? Sort out your database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your database credentials do not have the right permissions to your database. I would recommend validating them again and the flushing the privileges. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: I used phpadmin to try to review the permissions of the database, but ultimately i had no idea what i was doing and ended up locking myself out of mysql.  Im not exactly sure what things i need to make sure match for the credentials.  I tried changing the passwords of users to what i have in my code but that was what ended up locking me out originally.